# How to add a TableView Controller as a subView to a UIViewController without using IB?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a requirement where after the login, i need to show a tabbar with four tabs and load a tableview controller with a navigation controller. The Login Page is a uiviewcontroller. I tried to add a tableviewcontroller as a subview to the first uiviewcontroller. But i am getting the view below the mentioned coordinates. I specified the coordinates as 0,0 but the tableviewcontroller is getting displayed a bit below the coordinates. Please help me.

[image]

The Blue background on the top is the First Login View but when i add the second tableviewcontroller as a subview it is getting displayed 15 pixels down the actual coordinates. Please help me. Let me know if i am going wrong some where. Thanks a lot.

```
_mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc]init];
        [self.view addSubview:_mainMenuViewController.view];
```

I have added a tableviewcontroller class and tried to add this as a subview in the above mentioned context...

Comment: Can you put the code of how do you add it?

Comment: When you say you specified the coordinates, are you referring to the view's `frame` or `bounds`?  Agree, let's see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View controllers know whether the window that they're in has a status bar and will adjust their views accordingly. So nesting them in non-Apple-sanctioned ways causes both view controllers to move their contents down by 20 points.

TabBar controllers are meant only to be used as a root-level view controller, so add it as a direct subview of your window.  Then add a navigation controller as a tab, and a table view to the navigation controller.  Present the login screen as a modal view controller.

Comment: I understand and accept that TabBar Controllers are the root-level view controllers but the problem here is... First i want a UIViewcontroller as a login screen and then want to load the Tabbar Controller. Here in my application i am loading the Login View Controller from the AppDelegate and then after valid credentials i need to load the Tabbar controller. How can i do this? Where do u want me to add the TabBar Controller? If i add the TabBar Controller in the AppDelegate Window, when can i load it?

Comment: Just design your UI as usual with the tab bar controller as the root view controller.  When your app starts, present the login view controller modally (non-animated).  When login is successful, just dismiss the modal view controller.